# How to write right regex for route?

Tags: php, regex, symfony, yii2

In my Phpdoc I have such setting for route.

```
* @route   /v1/posts/<type:(news|article|release|about)?>
```

How to make it so that the slash after the "posts" was inserted only when the type is passed.

Comment: Try `/v1/posts(?:/<type:(news|article|release|about)>)?`

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make the `type` alternation group obligatory and wrap the `/type..` part with an optional non-capturing group:

```
/v1/posts(?:/<type:(news|article|release|about)>)?
```

Now,

- `/v1/posts` - matches a literal substring
- `(?:/<type:(news|article|release|about)>)?` - matches 1 or 0 occurrences (i.e. this part may be missing) of

  - `/` - a slash
  - `<type:(news|article|release|about)>` - `<type:`, then any of the alternatives inside the capturing group, and then `>`.